# How to use the same argument twice in a single line?

Tags: python, string, join, discord, arguments

I have this code for my discord bot:

```
@bot.command(brief="Za map napiš Rod a druh a vyskočí ti mapa výskytu!")
async def map(ctx, *args):
    if not args:
        await ctx.channel.send("Nenapsal jsi Rod/ Rod a druh! \nVysvětlivka:")
        await ctx.channel.send(
            "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/661985293834125342/808308254081417227/acz_map_command.png"
        )

    else:
        await ctx.channel.send('Mapa výskytu: *{}*'.format(
            ' '.join(args).capitalize()))
        await ctx.channel.send(
            'https://antmap.coc.tools/images/{}.png '.format(
                '.'.join(args).capitalize()))
        await ctx.channel.send('AntWiki: *{}*'.format(
            ' '.join(args).capitalize()))
        await ctx.channel.send(
            'https://antwiki.org/wiki/{}'.format(
                '_'.join(args).capitalize()))
```

The problem is here:

```
        await ctx.channel.send(
            'https://antmap.coc.tools/images/{}.png '.format(
                '.'.join(args).capitalize()))
```

Bot sends this after you use the command: https:/antmap.coc.tools/images/Argument1.Argument2.png

But now I need to change it, so it sends https:/antmap.coc.tools/images/Argument1/Argument1.Argument2.png

Should it look like this:

```
             'https://antmap.coc.tools/images/{}/{}.png'
```

or like this:

```
'https://antmap.coc.tools/images/{}.png'.format(
                '/','.'.join(args).capitalize()
```

or something like that?

I have searched the answer a bit, but I couldn't figure it out yet.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```python
'https://antmap.coc.tools/images/{}/{}.{}.png'.format(arg1,arg1,arg2)
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#the-string-format-method