# Positional arguments error in repl.it discord bot

Tags: python, discord, arguments, position

My code: https://replit.com/@Jakubidlk/AntsCzech-BOT#main.py
Problem: bot command !acz maps:
My error:

```
   'https://antmap.coc.tools/images/{0}/{0}.{1}png'.format('/'.join(args).capitalize()))
IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/bot.py", line 902, in invoke
   await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
 File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 864, in invoke
   await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
 File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/ext/commands/core.py", line 94, in wrapped
   raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple
```

How to fix this thing? I was searching all for so long now

Answer (score 0):

Reading from your Exception traceback I suspect that the issue is at here

```
https://antmap.coc.tools/images/{0}/{0}.{1}png'.format('/'.join(args).capitalize()))
```

You are using two placeholders here, `{0}` for first positional argument, `{1}` for second positional argument. But you are passing only single positional argument to the `format` function hence the `IndexError`

```
>>> "{0} {1}".format("first", "second")
'first second' # Works fine.
>>> "{0} {1}".format("first") # Wrong no of arguments here
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: Replacement index 1 out of range for positional args tuple
```

Comment: Ok then, how do I convert one argument into two? Command is !acz maps Lasius flavusIf Lasius flavus is considered as one, then how do I make it in to two? Im desperate here

Comment: @JakubŠidlík If you have only one argument, you must only use single placeholder.ie, `{0}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67120978/how-to-use-the-same-argument-twice-in-a-single-line welllllll